# How can I bring back the war proposal notification in Stellaris?

Tags: stellaris

My alliance had suggested we go to war with someone I wanted to go to war with for a while, but before I could accept it, I saved my game just in case. Then loaded it again.

Now the proposition on the top is not there anymore and I cannot for the life of me find this war proposal anywhere.

It hasn't been declined, it just disappeared, because when I go to declare war against that enemy, it says: "Your alliance already has a proposition for actions against this empire."

What am I suppose to do? Just wait until the offer dies and it auto-declines? But then I lose -20 reputation with my entire alliance.

Wtf...

Comment: Can'T say for certain, but check the alliance screen (the button with the handshake in the bottom right). The war propsal may be there. If not, it's most likely a bug and you have to wait for it to expire.